# Duplicate Records From Postgres SELECT SETOF Function

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I am returning a SETOF from a Postgres FUNCTION to PHP/PDO. Unfortunately, I am getting 2 copies of every row returned.

Here is the Postgres TYPE:

```
CREATE TYPE marker AS (i BOOLEAN, r DOUBLE PRECISION, la DOUBLE PRECISION, lo DOUBLE PRECISION, n INTEGER);
```

And the FUNCTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rl_select_markers (latitude DOUBLE PRECISION, longitude DOUBLE PRECISION) RETURNS setof marker AS $$
DECLARE
ROW marker%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR ROW IN SELECT is_male, rate, lat, lon, (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - created_at)/60)::INTEGER FROM markers 
    WHERE expires_at > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_Point(longitude, latitude), geog, FALSE) LIMIT 25 
    LOOP
    RETURN NEXT ROW;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is the relevant PHP:

```
$dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db, $user, $pw);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT rl_select_markers (:lat, :lon)");
$stmt->bindParam(':lat', $lat, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':lon', $lon, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$keys = array('i', 'r', 'la', 'lo', 'n');
$markers = array();
while ($lines = $stmt->fetch()) 
{   
    $log->logInfo($log_id . " lines=" . $lines);
    $combined = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line) 
    { 
        $log->logInfo($log_id . " line=" . $line);
        // Remove brackets around $line and put in array
        $vals = explode(",", substr($line, 1, strlen($line)-2));
        // Combine into key value pairs
        $combined = array_combine($keys, $vals);
    }
    $markers[] = array("m"=>$combined);
}

$dbh = null;
$stmt = null;

$log->logInfo($log_id . " Send 200 OK");
sendResponse(200, json_encode(array("mks"=>$markers)), "application/json");
```

The unexpected behaviour is that each `$lines` is an array of two copies of the same line.

E.G. When there is one record to return `$lines` would be an array of 2 strings that are exactly the same. So the above logging will produce:

```
lines=Array
line=(f,10,51.505601,-0.109917,8)
line=(f,10,51.505601,-0.109917,8)
```

I understand my inner PHP loop is nonsense but it works. I can see work arounds (such as add a `break;`)but want to remove the duplication.

I hope I have explained this clearly. Can you see why I am getting these duplicates of every record?

**Edit**

Following @a_horse_with_no_name's comment question:

Calling the SQL or the FUNCTION from phpPgAdmin does **not** produce the duplicate.

Comment: Do you get those duplicates also when running the query in a SQL client like psql (i.e. outside of PHP).

Comment: The lonely `RETURN;` is unnecessary in your function.  Not that this is any kind of solution for you...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: When I run the SQL in phpPgAdmin I do not get the duplicate.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Also when I run `SELECT rl_select_markers(1,1);` in phpPgAdmin I get no duplicate

Comment: @dezso: Thanks. Removed. But as you said, it doesn't stop the duplicates.

Comment: Is there any good reason to use a function instead of a view (or even a plain select) here?

Comment: So this means the problem is in the PHP code, not the SQL code.

Comment: @wildplasser: Probably no reason except for my ignorance. This is my first outing with Postgres and I automatically go for a FUNCTION. So I understand view but what do you mean by 'a plain select'? If you mean the SQL in the PHP/PDO my reasoning was that a DB function would be more efficient. Am I wrong?

Comment: The only possible efficiency gain is in (avoiding) the parsing. But compared to the ST_distance() for ordering that *could* be futile. The only way to find out is: measure it. I don't know if the cursor comes without cost, a plain query would have a "hidden" internal cursor somewhere, too IMHO.

Comment: @wildplasser: Thanks. Yes I take your point that ST_distance is such a big hit but it's the best I could find to grab nearest 25 locations. Please point me to a better way if it exists!

Comment: If you don't have a performance problem then you shouldn't bother. Generally, there is no "better" way, but do keep in mind that in the worst case the query would have to inspect *all* the rows just to find the top 25. (a query plan would reveal that). The cost of the distance calculation also depends on the nature of the other part of the comparison (geog), which could be a polygon, with or without additional info (such as the bounding box) YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you've made a mistake thinking that `fetch()` function would return multiple rows — it always returns one row — an array of columns.

As default `$fetch_style` is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` this array is indexed on both column name and 0-indexed column number and has two elements for every column:

```
0 => (f,10,51.505601,-0.109917,8)
'rl_select_markers' => (f,10,51.505601,-0.109917,8)
```

So:

- use fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM), so you'll get a number indexed column;
- get rid of `foreach ($lines as $line)`
- rename variable `$lines` to `$line`
- just use `$line[0]`

Corrected code:

```
while ($line = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) 
{   
    $log->logInfo($log_id . " line=" . print_r($line,TRUE));
    $combined = array();
    // Remove brackets around $line and put in array
    $vals = explode(",", substr($line[0], 1, strlen($line[0])-2));
    // Combine into key value pairs
    $combined = array_combine($keys, $vals);
    $markers[] = array("m"=>$combined);
}
```

*PHP GOTHA Nr 64372*

Even better: I'd use `select (rl_select_markers (:lat, :lon)).*` query and then just:

```
while ( $combined = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $markers[] = array("m"=>$combined);
}
```

Comment: I was very surprised that `fetch` returned an array. Sure I could grab the first index but that still involves PDO grabbing duplicates (and me ignoring them). Which is not ideal.

Comment: I do not immediately understand your improved code. A quick search for 'PHP GOTHA Nr 64372' does not find anything. I shall investigate your code further when I have some time this afternoon. Thank you.

Comment: This _PHP GOTHA Nr 64372_ is a joke, you know. About how terrible PHP is.

Comment: Your code is way better than your joke :). Your solution works perfectly. Grabbing the associated array is something I had failed with before your help. But something confounds me. I have been staring at it for hours. **Where do the keys come from?** Really you have to tell me. I can only guess it is the first letter of the cols with 'la' & 'lo' used because of the common 'l' and 'n' is used for an int value. Is that really it?? If so, is this PDO? This can't be it. I must missing something really obvious. Please put me out of my misery. And thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Keys are from Postgres — from `marker` type definition. Try to run this `select (rl_select_markers (:lat, :lon)).*` on phpPgAdmin or psql — keys can be seen as column names in result.